# Solution of a vector PDE $\partial_t W = A(x) W(x,t) + B(x) \partial_x W$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the 2x2 matrix PDE
$$ \partial_t W(x,t) = A(x) W(x,t) + B(x)\partial_x W(x,t) $$
where $W(x,t)=\begin{bmatrix} W_1(x,t), W_2(x,t) \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $A$ and $B$ are 2x2 matrices which depend on $X$. Notably, the matrix $A(x)$ is singular. $B(x)$ is well-behaved and has an inverse.

Were this a simple first order PDE (not a vector PDE), I would proceed via the method of characteristics:
$$ \frac{dt}{1} = -\frac{dx}{B(x)} = \frac{dW}{A(x)}. $$
Instead, I am unsure what to do here.
How does one find the characteristics of a PDE when the coefficients are matrices?